# How to use async and await correctly in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

When i run `console.log (f ())` i want it returns the data that came from `getData (url)`, but it keeps returning `Promise {<pending>}`. I thought using `await` keyword would solve this by making the code execution stops until`getData ()`returns something. I know if i use `f().then(console.log)` it will work fine, but i just don't understand why `console.log (f())` does not works too.
There is a way to achieve the same result `f().then(console.log)` but not using the `then ()` function?

```
async function f() {
    const url = `https://stackoverflow.com`;
    let d = await getData(url);
    return d;
}

console.log(f());
```

If it is impossible, can you explain why?

Comment: *"If it is impossible, can you explain why?"*  An `async` function always returns a promise, because it doesn't know when the things it `await`s are done. You cannot eat pizza before it was delivered. `async/await` is not blocking, it just provides a nicer way to deal with async code.

Comment: try `console.log(await f())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` is an async function, so it still returns a Promise.

To wait for this promise to resolve you need to `await` it.

```
(async () => console.log(await f())();
```

Or in long:

```
async function run(){
   console.log(await f());
}
run();
```

Answer (score 3):

`async` and `await` do not stop functions from being asynchronous.

An `async` function will *always* return a Promise. It just resolves to whatever you `return` instead of requiring that you call `resolve` function with the value.

Inside an `async` function, you can `await` other Promises. This **simulates** non-asynchronous code, but it is just syntax. It doesn't let you do anything you couldn't do with `then()`, it just gives you a simpler syntax.